# global variable is not incrementing properly

Tags: c, global

```
int count;
int main(){
count=0;

    printf("%6d\t    %6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,multiFib(i),count);
}

int multiFib(int x){

if (x<2){
    return 1;
    count++;
}}
```

In this code, `count` always gives 0 result. I made it a global variable, not to define it in the function again.  How can I increase that variable?

It outputs in order; that is not problem. It gives the result:

```
1    1 0
-

2    1 0
-

3    2 0
```

So, `count` is not increasing — but why?

Comment: Please take more care of your writing when asking here.

Comment: any answers?global variable does not incrementing.

Comment: Copy-pasting an error message telling you to expand a question in order to do so is the surest way to gather negative attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although order of evaluation is not guaranteed (see multiple other answers), there is another, more fundamental problem (actually, two of them):

```
int multiFib(int x)
{
    if (x<2){
        return 1;
        count++;
    }
}
```

1. You attempt to increment `count` after you've returned from your function. Your compiler should be warning about unreachable code.
2. You don't return a value from `multiFib()` when the input is bigger than 2.

The fragment of `main()` that you show references an undefined variable `i`. I assume that is because you deleted a `for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)` loop from before the `printf()` statement. To fix the 'order of evaluation' problem, you might want to use:

```
int count;
int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        int fib = multiFib(i);
        printf("%3d    %10d    %10d\n", i+1, fib, count);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This evaluates the number of calls to `multiFib()` for each top-level call to the function.

For the `multiFib()` function itself, you probably need:

```
int multiFib(int x)
{
    count++;
    if (x < 2)
        return x;
    else
        return multiFib(x-1) + multiFib(x-2);
}
```

Though this is an appallingly slow implementation of Fibonacci numbers so you shouldn't use this as an answer to your homework (but it does make a 'working' function).

Example output:

```
  1             0             1
  2             1             1
  3             1             3
  4             2             5
  5             3             9
  6             5            15
  7             8            25
  8            13            41
  9            21            67
 10            34           109
 11            55           177
 12            89           287
 13           144           465
 14           233           753
 15           377          1219
 16           610          1973
 17           987          3193
 18          1597          5167
 19          2584          8361
 20          4181         13529
 21          6765         21891
 22         10946         35421
 23         17711         57313
 24         28657         92735
 25         46368        150049
 26         75025        242785
 27        121393        392835
 28        196418        635621
 29        317811       1028457
 30        514229       1664079
 31        832040       2692537
 32       1346269       4356617
 33       2178309       7049155
 34       3524578      11405773
 35       5702887      18454929
 36       9227465      29860703
 37      14930352      48315633
 38      24157817      78176337
 39      39088169     126491971
 40      63245986     204668309
```

Note that if you go much beyond 40, you start getting arithmetic overflow. It also gets to be very (very, very) slow.

Comment: I can only give +1... Good observation... Even I did answer, but I did not observed these things...

Comment: @NishithJainMR: I didn't notice the extra problems until the OP issued the plaintive "any answers? global variable is not incrementing" comment when there were already three answers giving the same (accurate as far as it went) analysis.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if (x<2){
    return 1;
    count++;
}
```

You return from the function *before* you increment count. So it's never incremented.

Return doesn't just set the returned value. It actually exits the function at that point.

Just swap the order of those two lines. Also, you should keep an eye on your compiler warnings. Any decent compiler will warn you that the `count++;` line is *unreachable*.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%6d\t    %6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,multiFib(i),count);
```

The order of function argument evaluation is unspecified in C. `multiFib` can be evaluated before or after `count` in the `printf` function call.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified. 
In your code,

```
printf("%6d\t    %6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,multiFib(i),count);
```

The argument to `printf` function `multiFib(i)` might be getting called after printing `count`.

Try this,

```
printf("%6d\t",multiFib(i));
printf("%6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,count);
```

to check the result.

Answer (score 1):

As it was said in another answers, problem is that order of evaluation of function arguments is not specified, so in your example:

```
printf("%6d\t    %6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,multiFib(i),count);
```

You can not be sure if `count` will be evaluated before or after passing `multiFib(i)` to the `printf()` function.

Please [look here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) for more detailed information about evaluation order in C++, or [here for evaluation order in C](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Order-of-Evaluation).

You might also find useful to force evaluation order by separating your `printf` into two calls:

```
printf("%6d\t",multiFib(i));
printf("%6d\t    %6d\t ",i+1,count);
```

like Nishith Jain M R suggested in his answer.

Comment: You can be sure that the value of `multiFib(i)` is evaluated before the value of `count` is printed; what you can't be sure is whether the `count` argument will be evaluated before or after the `multiFib(i)` argument to `printf()`.